# The page scrolls up instead of the caret moving down

Tags: css, textarea, richtextbox, rich-text-editor, wysihtml5

I use wysihtml5 editor. I can type a text normally only till it fits the textarea window. After that a scroll bar appears (which is fine) but let's say I want to type new line on the very top of the text area and when I press enter the line which was just typed moves up outside of the top border of text area and cursos stays on the same first line. So in order to see the first line in the document I just typed I need to scroll one line up. All that instead of the text line stays in place and cursor moves one line down.

That is not usual text editing beheavor. Why is that? Is that an CSS issue?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this has to be an attribute of the text area itself.. but I have no idea how.. I'm myself a beginner in this..

try to search for extra attribute of text-area like:

```
<textarea rows="2" cols="20" wrap="hard">
 .... 
 </textarea>
```

good luck..

Comment: Nop, didn't really work, but thank you for try I didn't know that property of textarea.